# How to open a program w/o stopping a CMD batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

How can I close the batch script window without first having to close the PDF file that is opened? Even with `exit` the window stays open until I close the PDF file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem query the registry to get the full path to acrobat
for /f "usebackq tokens=3*" %%a in (`reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ /s /f \Acrobat.exe ^| findstr Default`) do (
  set _acrobat=%%a %%b
  rem create the shortcut
  "!_acrobat!" /A "page=10" "file.pdf"
  )
endlocal
exit
```

Comment: I think you want the batch command 'START' - you use it to start seperate processes, and it returns immedately (meaning it'll immedately run the next command (being exit).

Comment: And insert a pair of double quotes `start "" "!_acrobat!" ...`otherwise start will take the first arg in quotes for the window title.

Comment: The script should work, but I don't have any systems with Acrobat loaded to check. I have tried it with other GUI programs and it works fine - the program is launched, the script completes and the command window closes, while the GUI remains open. I suggest you run it with `echo on` to see which commands are executed at what point.

Comment: @djsmiley2k - For a GUI program, `start` is called implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This command will not stop your batch file:

`start "" "%userprofile%\desktop\acrobat.exe.lnk"  /A "page=10" "file.pdf"`

```
@rem Windows 10 64-bit. Query registry.  Make link to acrobat.  Open .pdf w/o stopping the batch
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
for /f "usebackq tokens=3*" %%a in (`reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ /s /f \acrobat.exe ^| findstr Default`) do set zacrobat=%%a %%b
REM Make link
mklink "%userprofile%\desktop\acrobat.exe.lnk" "%zacrobat%" 
REM Open .pdf without stopping batch
start "" "%userprofile%\desktop\acrobat.exe.lnk"  /A "page=10" "file.pdf"
exit /b
```